# Use object destructuring prefer-destructuring

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am codding first time on Vue.js and I have problem. Can you describe me the solution or problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP9Sj.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code, the error message, and the location in which it is occurring, as text. Don't post links to paintings of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { data } = await ...
```

Use this in 108 and 97 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your promise object has a data element. Currently, you are accessing your data element using dot (.) syntax. ( Your promise object.data is returning data).

You can use object destructuring to directly access the data element from inside your promise object

```
const { data } = (await this.$api.auth.sighIN({
    email: this.email,
    password: this.form.password,
}));
```